# How to swap Red with Blue in RGB image and keep brightness?

Tags: delphi, bitmap

I am reading a 24 bit bitmap:

```
var P: PByteArray;
...
for y:=0 to Bmp.Height-1 do begin
    P := Bmp.ScanLine[y];
    for x:=0 to Bmp.Width-1 do begin
      R := P[3*x+2];
      G := P[3*x+1];
      B := P[3*x  ];
```

Now I swap RGB with BGR:

```
      P[3*x+2] := B;
      P[3*x+1] := G;
      P[3*x  ] := R;
```

So if I had something red on my image it's now blue, and what was blue is red. But the problem is the brightness changes and the new image is either darker or brighter then the source image.
How can I make my output image as bright/dark as the input image?

Comment: Convert to linear, weight it with a luminosity function : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relative_luminance

Comment: @J... So I should calculate old luminance, new luminance, divide new/old and then multiply my new B and new R by this value?

Comment: Yes, new luminance = old luminance, but swap the R/B weights in the luminosity function, not the RGB values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you first convert from RGB to [HSL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL_and_HSV).
Then turn the [colorwheel](https://richnewman.wordpress.com/2007/04/29/using-hsl-color-hue-saturation-luminosity-to-create-better-looking-guis-part-1/) (aka Hue, see below) to convert red to blue and convert back to RGB.
This should preserve the luminance.

Delphi has a unit that does just that: [`VCL.GraphUtil`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Seattle/en/Vcl.GraphUtil).

You can use:
[`procedure ColorRGBToHLS(clrRGB: TColorRef; var Hue, Luminance, Saturation: Word);`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Seattle/en/Vcl.GraphUtil.ColorRGBToHLS) and
 [`function ColorHLSToRGB(Hue, Luminance, Saturation: Word): TColorRef;`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Seattle/en/Vcl.GraphUtil.ColorHLSToRGB).

**Hue**

Hue is reasonably self-explanatory, and starts at 0 for red. As its value increases it goes through the colors of the rainbow. I have not tested what the GraphUtils output, but if a circle has 256 degrees the values are:

- Red 0
- Orange 20
- Yellow 40
- Green 80
- Cyan 120
- Blue 160
- Violet 180
- Magenta 200
- Pink 220

*It's unhelpful that Embarcadero uses the non-standard `HLS` instead of `HSL`, but that's life.*

Comment: Thanks, I tried this approach and got a blue image but it's not as bright as the source red one: http://pastebin.com/zG2PgFFU

Comment: Maybe check the details of the above functions and tweak them using the luminance wiki data?